# How to restrict user scanner input data type (java)?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, restriction

say, I want the user to input an integer only but not something like "bacon", is there a way  to restrict user input to integers(or other data types) so I don't get any errors and or inputs other than an integer?

Comment: bacon should be always allowed, no exceptions.

Comment: Not in a terminal window. The best you can do is validate the input.

Comment: You can keep asking for input until the user gives you an integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your Scanner has the name myScanner:

```
public static int checkMyInput () { 
    try {
        return myScanner.nextInt();
    } catch (InputMismatchException e ) {
         myScanner.next();
         System.out.println("bacon luff");
        return 0 ;
    }
}
```

and then you can call that method.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fully functional example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Temp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = 0;
        String input = "";
        String exit = "exit";
        boolean isStringNumber = true;//If the String is not Number

        System.out.println("NOTE: To exit, type the word exit and press enter key");

        while(true){

            System.out.println("\nPlease enter a number only...");
            input = inp.nextLine();

            if(input.equalsIgnoreCase(exit)){break;}

            isStringNumber = input.matches("[0-9]+");//Check if no digits in string

            if(isStringNumber == false){
                System.out.println("\nYou entered a non number " + input);
                System.out.println("Remove all non numbers from your input and try again !");
                continue;
            }else{
                num = Integer.parseInt(input);
                System.out.println("You entered " + num);
            }

        }

        System.out.println("Exiting program...");

    }

}
```

Comment: indeed a well written fully functional example, thanks a lot, I learned a lot from this, I'd give you an upvote if I have 15 rep :(. This can check if a String contains only a 1 digit number. But still, @user3793514 provided me a **direct solution** to my problem by providing a method that tests for input type.

Comment: @PotatoSalad - Thanks. I am glad you found it useful. If you want, you can give me a +1 :)