# How can i check/ ensure that the input is a float? I

Tags: java, floating-point

Is there a way to ensure that only a float is entered?  or should I have it as a string and parse it to be a float after checking it?

I have tried a do while loop with getClass() etc and none of it worked.

```
package methods;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class methods {

    public static void main(String[] args) { //start of the main method

        float tax, price, conv;
        System.out.println(" Welcome to the pricing program");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Please Enter the price ");
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
        price = kbd.nextFloat();

        tax = 0.2f;
        conv = addtax(tax, price);
        System.out.println(conv);
    }

    static float addtax(float methodtax, float methodprice) {
        return (methodprice + (methodprice * methodtax));
    }
}
```

Comment: Another option, if you had to take in a String, would be to parse the String for a float value and handle the Exception if its not a float. See https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Float.html#parseFloat(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the `InputMismatchException` prior to using the value. See the answer linked below for a couple of ways to do this

[How to restrict user scanner input data type (java)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24982642/how-to-restrict-user-scanner-input-data-type-java)